# How to use Options attribute in primeng Schedule?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng

I am using primeng schedule i.e fullcalendar

ts file: 
`optionsObj:Object={
timeFormat: 'hh:mm a'
}`

html file:

`<p-schedule [eventLimit]="4" [options]="optionsObj"></p-schedule>`

the above code is giving
"Can't bind to 'options' since it isn't a known property of 'p-schedule"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is only since a couple of days that the options property was added (version 2.0.0-RC3) so make sure you use PrimeNG 2.0.0-RC3 or higher.

See https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/1976